# Build a tree from a list of nodes and links

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

I have a graphical editor that allows to draw a d3 force directed graph (a questionnaire with multiple choices and outcome, for example,  if you answer yes to question 1, go to question 2, else go to question 1b).

It has a root node, and nodes can have multiple parents, and multiple children.

Internally, it is represented as a list of nodes and a list of links.

### Example input

```
const nodes = [
    {id:1, data: {display: "start"}},
    {id:2, data: {display: "question 1"}},
    {id:3, data: {display: "question 2"}},
    {id:4, data: {display: "question 1b"}},
    {id:5, data: {display: "End"}},
];
   
const links = [
    {source:1,target:2},
    {source:2,target:3},
    {source:2,target:4},
    {source:4,target:3},
    {source:3,target:5},
];
```

### Expected output

I need to generate a tree showing all possible paths, like so:

```
{
    Id:1
    Data: {display: "start"},
    Children: [
        {
            Id:2,
            Data: {display: "question 1"},
            Children:[
                {
                    Id:3,
                    Data: {display: "question 2"},
                    Children:[
                        {
                            Id:5
                            Data: "End",
                            Children:[]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    Id:4,
                    Data: {display: "question 1 b"},
                    Children:[
                        {
                            Id:3,
                            Data: {display: "question 2"},
                            Children:[
                                {
                                    Id:5
                                    Data: "End",
                                    Children:[]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

### Attempt

Here is my (very naive) try at it so far:

```js
const nodes = [
    {id:1, data: {display: "start"}},
    {id:2, data: {display: "question 1"}},
    {id:3, data: {display: "question 2"}},
    {id:4, data: {display: "question 1b"}},
    {id:5, data: {display: "End"}},
];
   
const links = [
    {source:1,target:2},
    {source:2,target:3},
    {source:2,target:4},
    {source:4,target:3},
    {source:3,target:5},
]

const startNode = nodes.find(n => n.id == 1);

const jsonTree = {
    id: startNode.id,
    data: startNode.data,
    children: [],
}

const nodeList = [];
nodeList.push(startNode);

while (nodeList.length > 0) {
    const currentNode = nodeList.shift();
    if (!currentNode) continue;
    currentNode.visited = true;
    const childNodes = this.findChildrenOfNode(currentNode, nodes, links);
    const position = this.findPositionInJson(jsonTree, currentNode);

    position.data = currentNode.data;
    position.id = currentNode.id
    childNodes.forEach((c) => {
    if (!c.visited) {
        c.visited = true;
        nodeList.push(c);
    }
    const child = {
        id:c.id,
        data: c.data,
        children: [],
    };

    position.children.push(child);
    });
}

function findChildrenOfNode(node, nodes, links) {
    const childLinksTargetIds = [];

    links.forEach((l) => {
      if (node.id === l.source) childLinksTargetIds.push(l.target);
    });
    return nodes.filter((n) => childLinksTargetIds.includes(n.id));
 }

function findPositionInJson(jsonObject, node) {
    if (!jsonObject) return null;
    if (jsonObject.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
      if (jsonObject.id === node.id) return jsonObject;
    }

    const keys = Object.keys(jsonObject);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
      const key = jsonObject[keys[i]];

      if (typeof key === 'object') {
        const o = this.findPositionInJson(key, node);
        if (o != null) return o;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

console.log(jsonTree)
```

### Question

My code will populate the direct children of "1b", but not recursively (The child of "1b" is "2", whose child should be "end")

I suppose there is an algorithm for doing exactly what I'm trying to do. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an map for mapping `id` values to the corresponding objects. Add to each of those objects an empty `children` array property. Then populate the `children` arrays from the `links` information, each time looking up the `source` and `target` identifiers in the map. Finally return the map entry for id 1:

```js
function buildTree(nodes, links) {
    let map = new Map(nodes.map(o => [o.id, {...o, children: []}]));
    for (let {source, target} of links) map.get(source).children.push(map.get(target));
    return map.get(1);
}

// Demo
const nodes = [
    {id:1, data: {display: "start"}},
    {id:2, data: {display: "question 1"}},
    {id:3, data: {display: "question 2"}},
    {id:4, data: {display: "question 1b"}},
    {id:5, data: {display: "End"}},
];
   
const links = [
    {source:1,target:2},
    {source:2,target:3},
    {source:2,target:4},
    {source:4,target:3},
    {source:3,target:5},
]

console.log(buildTree(nodes, links));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion for a shorter solution:

```js
const nodes = [
   {id:1, data: {display: "start"}},
   {id:2, data: {display: "question 1"}},
   {id:3, data: {display: "question 2"}},
   {id:4, data: {display: "question 1b"}},
   {id:5, data: {display: "End"}},
];

const links = [
   {source:1,target:2},
   {source:2,target:3},
   {source:2,target:4},
   {source:4,target:3},
   {source:3,target:5},
];
var nds = Object.fromEntries(nodes.map(x => [x.id, x.data]))
function to_tree(n = 1){
   return {Id:n, data:nds[n], children:links.filter(x => x.source === n).map(({source:_, target:t}) => to_tree(t))}
}
console.log(to_tree())
```